# Picking a server control depending on environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page that references a server control from an assembly and lives in Sharepoint (knowledge/experience in Sharepoint is not required to answer this question, i'm simply giving you context). The implementation looks something like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wc" Assembly="Test.Controls" Namespace="Test.Controls" %>    
<wc:WYSIWYG runat="server"></wc:WYSIWYG>
```

I can NOT change the .aspx page's content which currently lives in Sharepoint and I have to to take the same code and run it outside of Sharepoint but still on an ASP.NET environment. It's cool and crazy at the sametime, I know.

**Challenge**

When this aspx page is running in Sharepoint, I have to get the WYSIWYG editor control to use Sharepoint's WYSIWYG control. When the same aspx page is running outside of Sharepoint but still in an ASP.NET environment, I need it to use a different server control that's not dependent/from Sharepoint. How could I modify the code-behind to perform this toggling? Is this even possible? Does my question even make sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You create a wrapper controller (which I assume is wc:WYSIWYG). In it you check if you are running inside a SharePoint environment or not, and the use LoadControl of the appropriate control for your environment. That's one way to solve it.

Comment: Is there another way we can new up a control? I would like to stay away from LoadControl().

Comment: Just curious why you don't want to use loadcontrol?